# When I submit a Spark job through Pyspark, how can I ensure which Python is used on the workers?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

Is it enough to make sure that PYSPARK_PYTHON is set in conf/spark-env.sh to point to the correct Python on those workers, or does something else need to be done as well?

Answer (score 1):

sorry, I misunderstand your question...I think "PYSPARK_PYTHON" is good enough, if you want to double check then maybe you can try **[Chef](https://www.chef.io/)** or **[Puppet](https://puppetlabs.com/)** to deploy same environment (including python path) for all your masters and workers.

---

I'm not sure which version you are using, but latest 1.5.1, you can use web interface to monitor your job statusat

```
http://<server-url>:18080

http://<driver-node>:4040
```

> You can access this interface by simply opening
>   http://:4040 in a web browser. If multiple SparkContexts
>   are running on the same host, they will bind to successive ports
>   beginning with 4040 (4041, 4042, etc).

You can read more about [Monitoring and Instrumentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/monitoring.html)

Comment: This does not answer my question